# How to render the main menu in alphabetical order regardless of menu link weight?

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

We are using the main menu of Drupal to build out the main navigation of the site. The content creators have access to add a menu link for a node in any level of the main menu and they are also able to use the weight field to set the location of where the menu link will fall under.

We are using a superfish menu block to render our main menu. We are having trouble figuring out how to always alphabetize regardless of what the current user's language is. How would we accomplish this?

Example scenarios:

1. For English content, the main menu will display all links only when the user's locale is English. Additionally all menu links for English should always be alphabetized regardless of the menu link weight.
2. For Japanese content, the main menu will only display Japanese menu links, but also in alphabetical order
3. For German content, the main menu will only display German menu links but also in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the menu link weight is the same, then the alphabetical order will be applied.